# How to achieve unary left fold / left to right evaluation order for variadic parameter call

Tags: c++, c++17, parameter-passing, variadic-functions, fold

There are scenarios, that require a guaranteed left to right evaluation sequence when expanding fold expressions into the parameter list of a function/functor.

**Example**

`r = f2(f(x)...)`

**Problem**

`f` is evaluated in order `f(x[n-1]), f(x[n-2]), ... f(x[0])` and it's results passed to `f2` the other way around (`f(x[0]), f(x[1]), ... f(x[n-1])`).

**Thoughts**

For initializers like `initializer{f(x)...}` would evaluate and pass in ltr order.
Expanding over the comma operator like `(f(x),...)` does evaluate left-to-right, but does not allow to return a data convolution.

Something like `r = f2(...f(x))` to express a unary left fold'ish evaluation desire is invalid.

Returning into a tuple using an intializer list like `std::tuple{f(x)...}` and pass the flattened result might work, but appears pretty inefficient having those intermediate steps.

**Demo**

A simple demo to visualize:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <array>

int main () {
    constexpr std::array is{ 0,1,2,3 };
    int eval{ 0 };
    auto res = std::apply([&](auto&&... v) {
        return std::tuple_cat([&](auto& val) {
            return std::tuple{ val, eval++ };
            } (std::forward<decltype(v)>(v))...);
        }, is);
    std::apply([](auto&&... v) {((std::cout << v),...); }, res);
}
```

Output:

- as-is: `03122130`
- to-be: `00112233`

How can I achieve a guaranteed left-to-right evaluation and passing into a variadic function order (ideally without overhead of index_sequence)?

Comment: Recursive template? You might fill a tuple that way. Or you might create an array or tuple with the results of the calls to `f` and `std::apply` `f2` to that one.

Comment: Function arguments never had specified order. If you want guaranteed order, do `std::tuple tup{f(x)...}; apply(f2, tup);`

Comment: @PasserBy Well, shouldn't you get the same problem with `f` getting called on constructing the tuple (-> constructor getting called like any other function)?

Comment: @Aconcagua [List initialization is left-to-right](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#4.sentence-2). Welcome to the world of wonderful C++ semantics I guess.

Comment: @PasserBy There's no wonderful at all actually, as this kind of initialisation can easily lead to unexpected results at other places (especially templates) – I even consider it *broken* – and now there's a place one would rely on :( – `std::tuple(f(x)...)` would't (necessarily) produce the equivalent result, I'd assume, as no brace initialiser applied – `tup = {...}` and `tup({...})` would compile, but the latter has different semantics (intermediate/temporary tuple!). My sole luck at this point: I usually don't rely on such evaluation order...

Comment: @PasserBy Still I assume most wouldn't really care about and just use that, so it kind of makes my own rather complex answer obsolete, doesn't it?